# Magento Search missing in Ultimo

Tags: magento

I am running Magento 1.9.2.4 with Ultimo theme on the website www.allycat.ph which is a Adult Toy site.  Anyway for some reason I can not get the search box to be displayed.  I have tried just about everything you can imagine after reading all the existing questions found on Stack Overflow and none seem to work.

I have used a tool that checked the core files to make sure no files are missing OR have been changed.

I have re-uploaded the theme in case a file is missing and still no luck.

If I change the theme to the stock standard theme then the Search is there and not missing at all - If I load a new install of Magento and then install the theme the search is also there but I can not work out why the search box WILL NOT display on the main store.

I would prefer to have the search on the top right hand side under the My Account / My Wishlist menu but I will open to having a different solution if required.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the search box is simply disabled on the server side, or whether there is a CSS issue that prevents it from rendering? Given that you've tried changing themes and restored the search that way, it sounds like a fault with the theme. I'd suggest examining the source code of the two themes and determining how the search box is different between them. Does it need certain id/classes, for example?

Comment: (Incidentally we discourage links to buggy websites here. This is not because your case is NSFW but because once you fix the live problem, the question will no longer demonstrate the issue, and the question will have to be deleted. We prefer questions that will last for posterity here, so if you can try to demonstrate the problem in the question itself, that is appreciated. If you do do some theme debugging, put what you find in the question! Thanks.)